# Validator Not Exists in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Im using validator for my laravel validation

I have this code that checks, column should be exists

`'table_id' => 'required|exists:table,id',`

Now i'm trying to check, if not exists.

Which means, request `table_id` should not be exists in the `table`

Comment: Super quick tip: **always check the documentation**, it is your best friend... Doing a simple search like "exist" on Validator docs will find you **unique** in the first places...

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `unique` validation rule.

You can read how to use it in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, the answer to your question, if I understand it very wellx, is **unique**, you use exists when you want to make sure that field is already in another table eg

```
'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users', 'exists:staff'],
```

that is the validation for my users table, what it means is that the email must not be in the users table, but the email must be in the staff table at the point of registering.